How can I get Ola Hallegrens index optimize script to select indexes with a certain name?
I'd like to use Ola Hallengrens Index Optimize procedure to rebuild indexes where the index name is like 'myindex%'.
I tried using the @indexes parameter like so:
use master
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'testdb',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@Indexes = '%.%.myindex%',
@LogToTable = 'Y' 

But I've discovered that the @indexes parameter relates to the table name, not the index name. I don't know why it is designed that way? But anyway, is there a way I achieve my aim using this procedure?

Your parameter value is incorrect. The value you're currently using is essentially looking for any table named "myindex%".
Assuming you want to perform maintenance on any index whose name matches the pattern myindex% in any database, in any schema, then the correct parameter value is:
@Indexes = '%.%.%.myindex%'

If you want to target a single database only:
@Indexes = 'testdb.%.%.myindex%'

Or if you want any database, any schema, but only tables named "tbl%" and indexes named "myindex%':
@Indexes = 'testdb.%.tbl%.myindex%'

This is because the code breaks apart the naming convention into four parts - Database, Schema, Table, Index - using the PARSENAME function.
You can use the @Databases parameter to limit this to a single database, but you still need to either put the DB name into the @Indexes parameter or use a wildcard for the Database portion of the @Indexes parameter.
